# Gap between images in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm building a scrollview with images 65x78 size. here is the code:

```
numberOfViews = [fotosJugadores count];

    for (int i = 0; i <    [fotosJugadores count]; i++) {

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[fotosJugadores objectAtIndex:i]];
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * myImage.size.width + 120;
        NSLog(@"my image %@", myImage);
        UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];
        awesomeView.tag = i;
        awesomeView.image = myImage;
        awesomeView.alpha = 0.5f;
        awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.jugadorSlide addSubview:awesomeView];
        awesomeView=nil;

    }

    [jugadorSlide setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    jugadorSlide.contentSize = CGSizeMake(65 * numberOfViews+240,78);
    jugadorSlide.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
    jugadorSlide.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [jugadorSlide setContentOffset:CGPointMake(((65 * numberOfViews)/2), 0)];
    //jugadorSlide.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
    [self scrollViewDidEndDragging:jugadorSlide willDecelerate:NO];
```

I'm trying to add a gap of 3 points more or less between images. I add space to the content size and the images x origin in order to leave space between last and first image and scroll view edges, so they always finish in center of scroll view. I  have tried different approaches, but I get images overlapped.

Thanks

Comment: You are not adding any gap between the images. The yOrigin value is always next to the previous image. Try using: `CGFloat yOrigin = i * (myImage.size.width +3) + 120;`. If that doesn't work, post an image so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: many thanks for your response, it works perfectly!!! Please, post your answer as it is, so I'll vote you  positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding any gap between the images. The yOrigin value is always next to the previous image.

You should add your margin (in your case 3 points) times the image index to the origin, like this: `CGFloat yOrigin = i * (myImage.size.width + 3) + 120;`